# Time Complexity of one basic example

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I ran into an example and want to calculate the order (time complexity) of this code. May someone help me understand how to calculate the order of this code:

```
f(n)
{
    i=0;
    while (n>0) {
        n=n/10;
        i=i+1;
    }
    return (i);
}
```

In fact, I think the order is `O(n/10)`. May any expert help me?

Comment: Please format the pseudo code

Comment: Dear @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc, would you please do it, to learn me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity is `O(log n)` because at each iteration n is divided by 10.

Proof with the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2): in your case, `a = 1`, `b = 10`, `c = log(a) = 0`, `k = 0`, so `T(n)=O(log n)`

Comment: Do you need to specify the base when it's `O(log n)`?

Comment: No - it's just multiplying by a constant

Comment: would u please add a bit detail how use this case of master theorem?

Comment: infact i dont know why O(n/10) is false?

Comment: I can prove it false: O(n) means that if n doubles, then the time doubles. In your case, to add just one iteration, you need to multiply n by 10. To double the time, you need to multiply n by itself (``n x n``)!

Comment: Dear @JeanLogeart, so we can say O(log n) in base 2? am i right?

Comment: It does not matter. But to be precise here, since you do ``n = n/10`` then the base is 10.

Comment: and my last question is how you use master theorem? master for solve recurrence relation ?

Comment: It is just a theorem to find the complexity of a recurrence relation

Comment: but you prove the complexity of code by master? if you add some detail it will be heplful.